# django manytomany self relation order by the middle table id

Tags: django

Model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
   friends= models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True, null=True)


friends = person.friends.order_by('friends__id')[:5]
```

I tried also

```
friends = Person.objects.filter(friends=obj).order_by('-friends__id')[:5]
```

I need to get the friends ordered by the middle table id (pk).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use intermediate table directly, and its no longer a queryset.

```
friends = [pf.to_person for pf in 
    person.friends.through.objects.filter(from_person=person)
    .select_related('to_person')
    .order_by('pk')]
```

Or you need to write raw SQL in ordering part.

```
person.friends.order_by(person.friends.through._meta.db_table+'.id')
```

Answer (score 0):

`friends = person.friends.order_by('pk')`

```
In [20]: [f.pk for f in p.friends.order_by('-pk')]
Out[20]: [3, 2]

In [21]: p.pk
Out[21]: 1

In [22]: [f.pk for f in p.friends.order_by('pk')]
Out[22]: [2, 3]
```

Comment: When I tried This It orders by the person id not the friends id

Comment: Still doesn't order by the middle table id