# Ordering many-to-many relations in Django models

Tags: django, django-models

Suppose you have a many-to-many relation in a Django model, such as:

```
class GroceryList(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(GroceryItem, related_name='in_lists')

class GroceryItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True)
```

You and me can both have the same items in two different lists, such as `Avocado`, and they will point to the same `Avocado` object.

What is the best way to implement an arbitrary **order** for items in each list, that can be edited separately for each list? (i.e. I have `Avocado` first in my list, while you have it at index `4`)

[django-ordered-model](https://github.com/bfirsh/django-ordered-model/) seems like an interesting solution, but it assumes global order across all objects.

Comment: If you use a through model, you can add a field for order to the M2M table - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships then retrieve items from a list ordered

Comment: Also, it seems django-ordered-model will soon have support for M2M https://github.com/bfirsh/django-ordered-model/pull/4

Comment: You should check this answer. I found what i was looking for
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10332848/11830115

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the intermediate table using [`through`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) and add the ordered field in that table.

```
class GroceryList(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(GroceryItem, related_name='in_lists', 
            through='Order')

class GroceryItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True)

class Order(models.Model):
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    gl = models.ForeignKey(GroceryList)
    gi = models.ForeignKey(GroceryItem)
```

So instead of doing `grocerylist.items.add(groceryitem)` you can do

```
#for groceryitem1 as 1st item in grocerylist1
Order.objects.create(gl=grocerylist1, gi=groceryitem1, number=1)

#for groceryitem1 as 10th item in grocerylist2
Order.objects.create(gl=grocerylist2, gi=groceryitem1, number=10)
```

Comment: This works (Django 1.10), but it results in the admin panel being fairly useless by default. One can adapt the code from [the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial07/#adding-related-objects) to add Inline addition of the new linking/through object. It's still not quite good if one has a lot of objects because the menu does not offer any way to search or order them. But perhaps someone can figure out a way to do that.