# Django Sort By Id Of ManyToMany table

Tags: django

So I have added a many to many relationship to my model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    cars = models.ManyToManyField(Car)
```

When I do:

```
bob.add(mercedes)
bob.add(bmw)
```

And then do person.cars.all(), I get:

```
[bmw, mercedes]
```

I looked in the many-to-many table and the order there is correct. So it's something like:

```
id    person    car 
1     bob       mercedes
2     bob       bmw
```

So all I need is to sort by many-to-many table's id column when retrieving cars. How to do it?

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901818/ordering-many-to-many-relations-in-django-models has the answer you need.

Comment: Have done! :) glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Ordering many-to-many relations in Django models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901818/ordering-many-to-many-relations-in-django-models) has th answer you need.

You basically have to manually specify the through table and guarantee the ordering in there.